# wxpython ogl package drag event

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm testing the ogl package in wxpython.

I want to drag a shape. And when I do drag it, I want a second shape to move at the same time. The problem is that I have not found a move/drag event. Only pre and post move events.

The only solution I can think of is to hide the second shape, and redraw it at the new position when the dragging is done.

And is the ogl package no longer maintained?

Oerjan Pettersen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OGL was part of the *contrib* directory in wxWidgets up until version 2.8; *contrib* has been removed in trunk and is no longer part of wxWidgets proper. You can find [OGL at wxCode](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/showcomp.php?name=ogl) now, but its status is shown there as unmaintained as well.

If you have not started yet using OGL, it's probably better not to do so.

Comment: The reason why I started using it, was because it was very simple to add a straight line between two bitmaps. And dragging was also very simple.
But I am not so deep into it yet, so I can find a different solution. Any ideas on how to draw a straight line between two bitmaps?

Comment: Drawing lines between bitmaps should be easy on a normal canvas object. Dragging would be more involved though. Maybe you can make use of the alternatives listed at http://wiki.wxpython.org/index.cgi/wxOGL?

Comment: Do you know anything about floatcanvas? Seems like it can do some of the same things as ogl.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Python, I have no experience with it and can't really help you with your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm jumping over to floatcanvas since they have a built inn zoom function. Might come in handy. :)