# Best canvas for drawing in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, canvas

I have to draw a graph of elements composing a topological model of a physical network. There would be nodes and arches, and the latter could be unidirectional or bidirectional.

I would like to capture the clicking events for the nodes and the arches (to select the element and show its properties somewhere), and the dragging events for the nodes (to move them around) and arches (to connect or disconnect elements).

I've done some research and I've narrowed the alternatives down to [OGL](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxOGL) (Object Graphics Library) and [FloatCanvas](http://wiki.wxpython.org/FloatCanvas). I would not like to go down to the DrawingContext, but it is not discarded if necessary.

Which canvas option would you choose?

Comment: I rolled my own.  Unforunately it was for work so I can't share the code.  http://www.michaelfogleman.com/2009/01/work-project-generic-diagram-widget/  It actually looks even nicer now, with gradients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried FloatCanvas, although there has been a lot of work to get everything to work. I've managed to get through mouse interaction things like connectivity, movement, automatic reconnection in case of movement, etc.

FloatCanvas is also quite nice in terms of performance and visual results. Anti-aliasing ([1](http://trac.paulmcnett.com/floatcanvas/wiki/SmoothLines)) ([2](http://trac.paulmcnett.com/floatcanvas/wiki/AlphaCircle)) is also possible to improve them if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that OGL is not being updated, and in general FloatCanvas looks more modern. I don't really know deeply enough the two options.

It seems that event capturing is easier with FloatCanvas. I would try to use it before OGL.

Comment: A related question seems to give more points for FloatCanvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824628/wxpython-ogl-package-drag-event

Comment: Neither OGL nor FloatCanvas seem to be actively updated.  Aside from a couple bugfixes, neither has had substantial commits for a couple years.
http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/3rdParty/FloatCanvas/
http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/trunk/wx/lib/ogl/