# Best Canvas for WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am a Java programmer working on a project in Python and the latest version of WxPython. In Java Swing, you can draw on JPanel elements by overriding their paint method.

I am looking for a similar class in WxPython for a GUI application.

I saw this question here:

[Best canvas for drawing in wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327918/best-canvas-for-drawing-in-wxpython)

but the fact that the projects are not being updated has me worried.

Three years later, is there anything else I should look into other than FloatCanvas or OGL?

The end use case i drawing a sound waves at varying degrees of zoom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a `wx.Panel`.

Here is some documentation on the drawing context functions:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdc.html

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html

```
import wx

class View(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
    def on_size(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        self.Refresh()
    def on_paint(self, event):
        w, h = self.GetClientSize()
        dc = wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawLine(0, 0, w, h)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 5))
        dc.DrawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, 100)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None)
        self.SetTitle('My Title')
        self.SetClientSize((500, 500))
        self.Center()
        self.view = View(self)

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: how do you handle zooming in such a "canvas" ?

Comment: Try `dc.SetUserScale` - http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#SetUserScale