# WxPython, Use of Buffered DC and Panel Refresh in a simple GUI (Rev counter and bar graph)

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, onpaint

I've just started programming in Python and have therefore had an attempt at a simple GUI that consists of a meter (rev counter) and a bar graph. This all works (the code is attached below). However I'm getting very bad flicker due to the screen refreshing (Windows XP). I know I need to use a Buffered DC however I can't work out from all the posts what I actually need to do.

However my assumptions are:

1. Initially create a Memory DC for the Buffered image to 'reside' in and then
2. Instantiate the Buffered DC
3. Bind the On Paint to the Buffered DC.

To provide the relevant meter face (scale) I've drawn it all in Autocad and have then converted it to a jpg (HMIV0.2.bmp) upon which the bar graph and meter needle are superimposed.

As you'll note I'm using the Refresh at the end of my loop and I'm wondering if this is 'bad practice'. However my intention is for the program to free run and 'pick up' the relevant values (revs) on each pass of the loop. Thereby having no external Event to trigger the paint.

Any advise or pointer in the right direction are highly appreciated...I bought Cody Precord's 'Wx.Python 2.8 Application Development Cookbook' in the hope of some inspiration but alas.

```
import wx
import random
import time
import math

def Data():
    data_value =random.randint(0,400)
    return data_value

def Pointer():
    meter_value =float(random.randint(0,260))
    Needle_centre_x = 253
    Needle_centre_y = 239
    Needle_length = float(125) 
    Needle_sweep = math.radians(214) #Number of degrees (converted to radians) that the needle is to deflect through
    Meter_max_scale = 260   # maximum value on the meter scale
    lo_reflect = float(20) # Meter reading that are less than this value are below the horizontal-Lo
    Angle_per_digit = Needle_sweep / Meter_max_scale # Angle_per_digit is in radians
    print '*******************NEW CYCLE*****************************'
    print 'The meter value is ' +str(meter_value)

    Start_displac =  Angle_per_digit * lo_reflect
    needle_ang =  -1*(Start_displac -(meter_value * Angle_per_digit))
    Needle_x = Needle_length * (math.cos(needle_ang))
    Needle_y = Needle_length * (math.sin(needle_ang))
    needle_degrees = math.degrees(needle_ang)
    anglea = needle_ang - math.pi/2
    angleb = needle_ang + math.pi/2
    base_x = 10*(math.cos(anglea))
    base_y = 10*(math.sin(anglea))
    print 'The needle angle is' + str(needle_degrees)
    print 'Angle A is ' + str(math.degrees(anglea)) 
    print 'Angle B is ' + str(math.degrees(angleb))    
    print 'The needle deflection angle is ' + str(math.degrees(needle_ang))  
    basea_y = int(Needle_centre_y- base_y)
    basea_x = int(Needle_centre_x - base_x)
    baseb_y = int(Needle_centre_y + base_y)
    baseb_x = int(Needle_centre_x + base_x)                 
    needle_y = int(Needle_centre_y - Needle_y)
    needle_x = int(Needle_centre_x - Needle_x)               
    Needle = [Needle_centre_x,Needle_centre_y,needle_x,needle_y,basea_x,basea_y,baseb_x,baseb_y] #Needle = [x1,y1,x2,y2,pointa_y,pointa_x,pointb_y,pointb_x]
    return Needle  

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,pos = (0,0), size = (800,500))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, data_value):           
        data_value = Data()
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("HMIV0.2.bmp")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)        

        if data_value > 300:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.RED_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*(data_value),2)
            dc.SetBrush(wx.BLUE_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*300,2)
            dc.SetBrush(wx.GREEN_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*200,2)

        if data_value < 300 and data_value > 200 :
            dc.SetBrush(wx.BLUE_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*(data_value),2)
            dc.SetBrush(wx.GREEN_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*200,2)

        if data_value < 200:
            dc.SetBrush(wx.GREEN_BRUSH)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(12,450,40,-1*(data_value),2)          

        dc.SetBrush(wx.BLUE_BRUSH)
        HMI_needle = Pointer()
        print 'the contents of HMI needle are' + str(HMI_needle)
        print 'Needle_centre_x,Needle_centre_y,needle_x,needle_y,basea_x,basea_y,baseb_x,baseb_y'
        print type(HMI_needle)
        Points = [(HMI_needle[2],HMI_needle[3]),(HMI_needle[4],HMI_needle[5]),(HMI_needle[6],HMI_needle[7])]
        dc.DrawPolygon(Points)
        dc.DrawCircle(253,239,20)                   
        time.sleep(0.1)    
        self.Refresh()     

 class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, wx.DefaultPosition, size,)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap("Background.jpg", type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.bitmap =wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap =bitmap)
        self.Panel = MyPanel(self)


app = wx.PySimpleApp(redirect=False, filename = "C:\output.txt", clearSigInt=True)
frame = MyFrame(None,"WxPaint", size=(800,500))#size=(800,480))
frame.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks,Foglebird! That worked a treat! Best regards, Rob

Answer (score 1):

- Use `wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM` on your `wx.Panel`
- Use `wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC` in your `OnPaint` handler

See my example code here:

[Best Canvas for WxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597110/best-canvas-for-wxpython/16616839#16616839)

Comment: FWIW using `wx.Panel` is really not necessary, a simple `wx.Window` would do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely good practice to put a delay in an event handler, mostly because it prevents other events from being handled.  Instead of ending your OnPaint handler with:

```
time.sleep(0.1)    
self.Refresh()
```

you should use:

```
wx.CallLater(100,self.Refresh)
```

In addition, I have found to avoid flicker, I disable background erase with:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, lambda x: 0)
```