# Python gui application tools?

Tags: python, winforms

What tools should be used to create GUI app in python? I imagine something similar to WinForms or WPF. It would be best if there were tools to design app visually. I think something similar to Java FX/Swing will do, too.

I tried tkinter framework, but it was impossible to use, it's very different from WinForms for example. In my app I will need canvas or something to draw few figures.

Comment: Gtk is available for python. i've only used it in `c`, but have seen python source which imports a `glade` file. `glade` is a screen painter for Gnu-Tool-Kit

Comment: check out wxPython for GUIs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597110/best-canvas-for-wxpython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend wxPython and wxGlade. The later includes a tutorial that should get you started with wxPython as well.

Depending on the type of drawing, matplotlib might be an option. wxGlade includes examples for this. Otherwise have a look at the link posted by wich or at the wxPython demo, whether the drawing capabilities match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are many GUI libraries.

1. [PyQt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/) is a cross-platform application framework.
2. [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/)
3. [PyGTK](https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK/)
4. [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) is available on Ardroid.

I think PyQt could help you. It has [GraphicsView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsview.html) class and you can draw something using it.