# Anti-Aliasing Images in a panel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm setting the shape of a wxPanel, but there are a lot of jagged edges. Is there a way to smooth these out?

Inside of the wx.Frame, I am setting the shape from a black and white .png image

```
mask = wx.Image('Resources/Images/Window/window_alpha_map.png')
mask.ConvertAlphaToMask()
shape = mask.ConvertToBitmap()
shape.SetMask(wx.Mask(shape, wx.BLACK))
self.SetShape(wx.RegionFromBitmap(shape))
```

Inside of the wxPanel, I am then setting the image in eraseBackground

```
def onEraseBackground(self, event):
        dc = event.GetDC()
        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)

        dc.Clear()

        background = wx.Image('Resources/Images/Window/window_background.png')
        bmp = background.ConvertToBitmap()
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Here are some examples of what I am talking about: http://clfu.se/PZn3 http://clfu.se/uE4

Is there a way to smooth these out in wxPython or even a trick in photoshop I am missing?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off to just draw the image using a GraphicsContext widget as that supports anti-aliasing:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GraphicsContext.html

wxPython also allows drawing via Cairo, which also support anti-aliasing:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingCairoWithWxPython

Finally, you could also take a look at FloatCanvas:

- [Best canvas for drawing in wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327918/best-canvas-for-drawing-in-wxpython)